# how HID device change to port (LPT&COM)?

Tags: converter, usb-device, digital-communications, hid

how HID device change to port (LPT&COM)?
there is an RFID reader that is already in the form of a USB, and is detected in the device manager as a HID, can the HID be converted into a serial port (COM&LPT)?

Answer (score 2):

Each USB device can describe the features and protocols it supports. Some protocols are standardized such as HID for keyboards, mice and game controllers, CDC ACM  for virtual serial ports or MSC for memory sticks. A device can support several of this protocols concurrently.

If your particular RFID reader only declares to support HID, there is no way to make it available as a serial port (unless you are willing to write complex device drivers and provided your operating system allows to interfere with standard USB protocols).

Comment: how to make device drivers for a new device,? because the RFID device I have read HID in the form of a USB input device

Comment: Writing a device driver very much depends on the operating system you are using. Which one is it? And if you haven't done it before, it will likely take you half a year. I very much doubt it is a sensible approach.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a Virtual Serial Port driver, that you have to write.

If your OS is Windows then you can write either a Custom Virtual Com Port - Kernel Mode or User Mode driver. But why do you we want to see the Hid device as a Com port, is there any requirements like your application will be able to read only serial port RFID reader and not able to read a Hid compliant RFID reader?

Writing a custom driver depends only on your requirements.

Most likely your RFID reader would be enumerated as a USB HID Keyboard.